# Как отсортировать записи по значению из связующей таблицы?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть таблица `posts`, которая имеет связь `has_many` с таблицей `ratings`. Таблица `ratings` содержит "историю" оценок постов (историю средних арифметический на момент сканирования).

Сейчас реализация такова:

```
joins(:ratings).order('ratings.value DESC NULLS LAST')
```

И это работает криво. В общем, сортирует не так как надо.

А хочется добиться сортировки постов по последнему значению в связующей таблицы `ratings` для каждого поста.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную проблему.

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример данных, ожидаемый и желаемый результаты.

Comment: @D-side у каждого поста от нуля и до бесконечности рейтингов. Посты нужно отсортировать по последней записи в `ratings`.

Comment: То есть, `ratings` вы хотите сортировать по убыванию `created_at`, но выбрать только по одной (первой) на пост (привет `DISTINCT ON`!). Гораздо проще держать актуальное среднее прямо в модели, подобно `counter_cache`. А пример всё-таки добавьте.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из существующей модели (насколько я понял конечно), SQL можно написать так:

Для случая если нужно взять последний рейтинг:

```
 select post.title, rating.value from posts, rating 
 where posts.post_id = rating.post_id and rating.created_at >= 
 (select MAX(created_at) as max_created from rating as rating_max 
      where rating_max.post_id = posts.id) 
 order by rating.value DESC NULLS LAST
```

Для случая если нужно по среднему арифметическому рейтингу, о чем путано упоминается в тексте вопроса:

```
 select post.title, AVG(rating.value) as avg_value from posts, rating 
 where posts.id = rating.post_id 
 group by posts.title
 order by avg_value DESC NULLS LAST
```

Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Я попытался реализовать с помощью вашего запроса, но, к сожалению, не получилось. Слишком много нюансов и из-за этого принял решение хранить актуальные значения сразу в родительской таблице. Как минимум, это упрощает запросы и их вес.

Comment: Вероятно надо находить способ сообщать обо всех нюансах, хотя бы для того чтобы люди не тратили зря время на пустые ответы